# How can I divide strings into different datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

This is how I add dataGridview Progmatically

```
DataGridView grid = new DataGridView();
    grid.Location = new Point(5, 30);
    grid.Width = container.Width - 10;
    grid.Height = container.Height - 40;
    grid.Name = "Section " + countSections.ToString();
    grid.Columns.Add("StudentID", "StudentID");
    grid.Columns.Add("StudentName","StudentName");
container.Controls.Add(grid);
```

Now we assumed that we have 5 dataGridView

```
     //I have list of students
string [] names = {"name","name2","name3","name4","name5","name6"};

//This is how I indentify DGV
foreach (Control grid in Pan.Controls)
{
    if (grid is DataGridView)
    {
        DataGridView myGrid = grid as DataGridView;
        //here how can i divide those names in different datagridview  
        //I use this syntax to add rows
        mygrid.Rows.Add(studentId,names);
    }
}
```

Giving you an Idea this module what I called auto sectioning, sorry for the logics ang ideas

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you have trouble with. Did you try `myGrid.Datasource = names;`?

Comment: What do you mean ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over your `names` array by obtaining its enumerator amnd then call MoveNext on it on each time you add the name to the DataGrid.

```
//I have list of students
string [] names = {"name","name2","name3","name4","name5","name6"};

// enumerator
var nameEnumerator = names.GetEnumerator();

//This is how I indentify DGV
foreach (Control grid in Pan.Controls)
{
    if (grid is DataGridView)
    {
        DataGridView myGrid = grid as DataGridView;
        // check if we still have names
        if (nameEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
          mygrid.Rows.Add(studentId, nameIterator.Current);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this will add only 1 row in every datagrid, what if you have a 4 datagridview ang 5 names ? where will be the 5th name ?

Comment: @dods try this one then. See if that better fits your needs

Comment: Im sorry but this only works in firstRow of the datagridview

Comment: I get it now, I user enumerator instead of for loop that avoid redundant, Also I added another loop  on how many times will i ireterate the rows

Answer (score 0):

```
//I have list of students
string [] names = {"name","name2","name3","name4","name5","name6"};

//This is how I identify DGV
int nameIndex=0;
foreach (Control grid in Pan.Controls)
{
    if (grid is DataGridView)
    {
        DataGridView myGrid = grid as DataGridView;
        //here how can i divide those names in different datagridview  
        //I use this syntax to add rows
        mygrid.Rows.Add(studentId,names[nameIndex++]);
    }
}
```